# QWebView mailto problem

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4, pyside

I'm using the QWebView element in a PyQt application and mailto 
links do not seem to work. When I click on them nothing happens and
the default mail client does not open.

Pointers on fixing this problem will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
self.connect(webview, QtCore.SIGNAL( " linkClicked ( const QUrl & ) "), self._link_clicked)
```

you could do open mail client in self._link_clicked

see also
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#signals

BTW, PySide is better than PyQt, the former is more Pythonic.

Comment: in that slot, you can use QDesktopServices::openUrl